# How do I integrate styles in other pages in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

Home page has got its style integrated but when I click about page which has no css or JS files but routes included even though the style is not getting included.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F2ks.png)

Comment: add all js and css into index.html in which view will be loaded

Answer (score 0):

Best way here is to use services which help you integrate to load css and js into the page. I would recommend to use the ff:

1. [CSS Injector](https://github.com/GabrielDelepine/angular-css-injector)
2. [Angular CSS](https://github.com/castillo-io/angular-css)

Please be advised that CSS injector may not work in IE7/8. So it's up to you to pick. Hope this may help you.